# What would be best to implement user to user chat functionality for android app?

Tags: android, chat

I want to integrate chat functionality within my app, so that user can chat with other connected user.
What would be best way to implement this?
Which API I should use?

I have researched some GCM and telegram API contents, both seems pretty time consuming and complex.

For telegram I found this content in some article
"Your app's source code has to be made public to comply with Telegram's policy (see https://core.telegram.org/api/ob...),"

This might not be agreeable for my application.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try Sockit.io for faster chat service.[native-socket-io-and-android](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the google talk API. It quite easy to build an XMPP client which allows you to have registertion, uptime and connectivity with ease.